# Unmatch plugin from updates?

Tags: plugins, updates

I have a plugin which I downloaded and removed alot off stuff I don't need from. I also renamed it for simplicity, but right now it is linked to some other plugin, close to the name I gave it.
If I go to Plugins under WP-Admin I can press View details. And it brings me information about a plugin with the name I gave it.

How do I unmatch this? So that it won't update if that plugins receives an update?

Thank you!

Comment: just give it another name or bump the version really high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name alone won't match. Name and slug will (slug = folder name that the plugin is in). Name and having the same author line will do the job too. Slug will match all by itself.

If you make a custom plugin for your site, name it after your site.

Plugin Name: Example.com custom plugin to do whatever

We obviously won't have a plugin named after your site, unless you wrote it.

Comment: Do the "Text Domain:" have to match the folder name and plugin name? At the top of the php file?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to rename it again. WordPress isn't terribly sophisticated in this regard. If a theme or plugin has the same name as one in the .org directory then it will be linked to that theme/plugin for updates and details.

You could also increase the version number to something unrealistic. That will prevent any updates from appearing as new updates, since yours will look newer, but it will still be linked in terms of details.

Edit: Otto’s comment made me realise I need to clarify that when I say rename, I mean rename the plugin *folder*.